# My binary search tree c program has a problem.I am using inorder traversal.only root node printed why?

Tags: c, recursion, struct, binary-search-tree, function-definition

it is a binary search tree with inorder traversal.there is an issue while printing elements.
I can't solve the issue.Only the root is gettting printed.it could be a semantic error also.Maybe there is issue in inserting.or some issue in displaying inorderly.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *llink;
        struct node *rlink;
    };
    typedef struct node bstnode;
    bstnode *root=NULL;

void insert(int ele)
{
    bstnode *cur,*prev,*temp;
    temp=(bstnode *)malloc(sizeof(bstnode));
    temp->data=ele;
    temp->llink=temp->rlink=NULL;
    cur=root;
    prev=NULL;
    if(root==NULL)
       root=temp;
    else
    {  
        prev=cur;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
         if(ele<cur->data)
            cur=cur->llink;
         else
           cur=cur->rlink;
        }
    if(ele<prev->data)    
      prev->llink=temp;
       else
        prev->rlink=temp;
    }
    //return root; 
}

void inorder()
{
if(root==NULL)
{
    return;}
else{
inorder(root->llink); 
printf("\n%d",root->data);
inorder(root->llink);
}
}

int main()
{
    insert(45);
    insert(76);

    inorder();
}
```

Comment: @bruno `inorder` also has problems.

Comment: Please format your code properly: appropriate indentation, and spaces around operators; `ele<cur->data` is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
else
{  
    prev=cur;
    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
     if(ele<cur->data)
        cur=cur->llink;
     else
       cur=cur->rlink;
    }
if(ele<prev->data)    
  prev->llink=temp;
   else
    prev->rlink=temp;
}
```

there is a logical mistake. The statement

```
    prev=cur;
```

shall be within the following while statement. For example

```
    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
     prev=cur;
     if(ele<cur->data)
        cur=cur->llink;
     else
       cur=cur->rlink;
    }
```

And the function `inorder`. Also incorrect because it is declared without a parameter

```
void inorder()
{
if(root==NULL)
{
    return;}
else{
inorder(root->llink); 
printf("\n%d",root->data);
inorder(root->llink);
}
}
```

Also there is used the data member `llink` two times.

It should be declared and defined like

```
void inorder( const bstnode *node )
{
    if ( node )
    {
        inorder( node->llink ); 
        printf( "\n%d", node->data );
        inorder( node->rlink );
    }
}
```

And it is called like

```
inorder( root );
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the part

```
        prev=cur;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
         if(ele<cur->data)
            cur=cur->llink;
         else
           cur=cur->rlink;
        }
```

is wrong.

Due to the wrong place of `prev=cur;`, `prev` will be only `root` instead of pointing at the node to be the parent of the new node.
The statement should be inside the loop:

```
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
         prev=cur;
         if(ele<cur->data)
            cur=cur->llink;
         else
           cur=cur->rlink;
        }
```

Secondly, the function `inorder` is wrong.
It is executed unconditionally when `root != NULL`.

Instaed of ignoring arguments and print `root` infinitely, it should take an argument to specify which node should be printed.

Using `llink` twich is also weird.

It can be like this:

```
void inorder(bstnode* node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else{
        inorder(node->llink); 
        printf("\n%d",node->data);
        inorder(node->rlink);
    }
}
```

And `inorder();` in the `main` function should be `inorder(root);`.